# Properties not listed in [Bind()] set to null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want that the values of some properties cannot be changed by the user while editing the form.

For example, an object has a number of properties that are set when it is created and should never be changed again. This can be the date of creation, the user who created the object, etc.

To do this, I specify in [Bind()] only the properties that are allowed to change, while when editing the object, all properties not specified in [Bind()] are set to null.
What are you do about it?

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is that you could [Bind()] all the fields in the model, but render the properties that you do not want the user to change as "hidden" or "readonly."

Hidden, if you don't need the user to see the property value:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MyUneditableProperty"/>
```

Readonly, if you want them to see it, but not edit it:

```
<input asp-for="MyUneditableProperty" readonly />
```

The problem with either of these two methods is that a user could alter the rendered HTML and make changes to these fields, which could allow them to change the values in a way you want to avoid.

I think it would be better to use a ViewModel that is separate from your entity model. A separate ViewModel would give you more control over the information the user can access, and it would eliminate the need for you to send and post fields that you don't want the User to edit anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
In this case, I see no difference between ViewModel and [Bind()]. In the ViewModel, I also put only those fields that users can change (for example, I do not specify the CreationDate field there). After the user submits the form built using the ViewModel, all fields not specified in the ViewModel are set to null.